# Compiling SASS dependencies in a publishable Nx/Nrwl library... NPM vs PNPM

Tags: angular, sass, postcss, nrwl-nx, pnpm

Given a single script run in both NPM and PNPM, the NPM version will succeed whereas the PNPM one fails.

`npx sass --style=compressed --load-path=node_modules ./lib/path/to/style.scss ./lib/prebuilt-themes/style.css`

`pnpx sass --style=compressed --load-path=node_modules ./lib/path/to/style.scss ./lib/prebuilt-themes/style.css`

The gist is a Sass file that uses `@use` to import **@material/*** mixins/functions. Those dependencies often include their own imports. For reference look to Angular Material's documentation for [theming components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components).

NPM is able to resolve these child imports no problem. In contrast, PNPM tries to pull in each module in the **@material** repo as a dependency, but since I haven't explicitly included these in my package, they're unavailable and the build fails. At this point, the only solution I've found is to import every module within **@material/*** which is quite heavy-handed for my liking. That or just stick to NPM - which as a company policy, isn't ideal. Including PNPM settings like `shamefully-hoist` hasn't had any success.

Alternatively, I've tried using PostCSS rather than node-scss but this fails either due to a peculiar bin error or an inability to set the node path for dependencies.

It's also important to note that this is explicitly in regards to compiling Sass as a standalone stylesheet within a publishable Nx library. As an Nx application, the scss compiles without issue, regardless of the manager being used.

Honestly, between tsconfig, postcss.config.js, package.json, project.json, and ng-package.json I'm at a loss as to what needs to changed and where. Any insight would be greatly apprecieated.